# android 3.4 - how to generate signed apk and build apk?

Tags: android-studio, apk, android-studio-3.0, sign

I'ved just updated from android studio 3.0.1 to 3.4, I cant seem to find the option to generate signed apk.

Also , I cant build apk, it has no effect. following is where I click.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjjEv.png

How to generate signed apk now for android 3.4 ?

Comment: please give screenshot of Help -> about (version)

Comment: @Axil any update on this one? very strange issue

Answer (score 1):

Click Generate Signed Bundle/APK in Build menu option.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ6O5.png

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved with this.

the project was opened with this and caused the problem:
- Open an existing Android Studio project

this actually solved the problem when i opened this way:
import project (Gradle, Eclipse, ADT, etc)

Answer (score 0):

try this

- Clean Project
- Rebuild project
- Invalidate Caches and Restart
- And then Build APK

Answer (score 0):

You need to first generate a private key using keytool, For Example:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks-keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias
```

The keystore as a file called my-release-key.jks, saving it in the current directory (you can move it wherever you'd like). The keystore contains a single key that is valid for 10,000 days

**Sign your app manually from the command line**

Sign APK to use `zipalign` and `apksigner` as described below.

**step 1:** Open Android Studio, select View > Tool Windows > Terminal—and navigate  directory where unsigned APK.

**step 2:** unsigned APK using zipalign:

```
zipalign -v -p 4 my-app-unsigned.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk
```

**step 3:**APK with your private key using apksigner:

```
apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.jks --out my-app-release.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk
```

**step 4:**Verify that your APK is signed:

```
apksigner verify my-app-release.apk
```

then Configure Gradle to sign your app